# Position image so that it always appears to the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

The image of the young lady on the following page: 
http://secretgenius.co.uk/document/document_index.html

needs to move to the bottom of the page if the content to the right is longer. You can see in the above URL that she is floating above the footer line, but I would like her to always appear on the footer line no matter how much content is to the right. I am using the 960.gs grid for this site.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:relative` on the image parent container, and `position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0` on the image

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: bottom` on the `img` tag

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
#mainFooter{ background: url(../images/footerbg.png) repeat-x left bottom; bottom:0px; width: 100%; position:fixed; }
#footer { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; padding:10px 0; }
```

try these settings & if any prior settings of css.
mainFooter: for img
& footer: for text bellow img